# Does the LEGO Dimensions gateway portal work across multiple systems?

Tags: lego-dimensions

Every copy of Lego Dimensions comes with a USB [Gateway Portal](http://lego-dimensions.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Gateway) for scanning characters, vehicles, and level packs into the game.

**Can these gateway portals be used across different consoles?**

For example, if I own the Wii U version of Lego Dimensions, will I need to buy another portal specifically for the PS3 version? Or can I reuse my old one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [Game Skinny article from 2015](http://www.gameskinny.com/6vkf7/7-things-you-should-know-before-playing-lego-dimensions), only the Xbox portals are console-specific:

> If you are playing using the Xbox 360 or the Xbox One, these pads only
>   work with their respective consoles because of Microsoft's peripheral
>   certifications. However the Wii U, PS3, and PS4 pads are interchangeable and you can
>   use one with any of the three consoles.

In other words, there are three base stations:

- Xbox 360
- Xbox One
- Wii U ⟷ PS3 ⟷ PS4

[Julio’s answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/336871/181240) supports this by mentioning that Disney Infinity bases have the same restrictions on Xbox.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the previous post, note that the Game Skinny article says,

> If you are playing using the Xbox 360 or the Xbox One, these pads only
>   work **with their respective consoles** because of Microsoft's peripheral
>   certifications...

So the answer should be:

- Xbox 360
- Xbox ONE
- Wii U ⟷ PS3 ⟷ PS4

I also happen to have Disney Infinity bases for Wii U, Xbox 360, and Xbox ONE, and can tell you that each respective Xbox Infinity base ONLY works with its own console, but my Wii U base works on PS4 and PS3 as well. I would imagine that Lego Dimensions and SkyLanders bases work the same way, with 3 unique versions of the base manufactured to span across all consoles.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I have edited my answer to reflect this info

Answer (score 1):

So, I know this is extremely late (4 years later) but at the bottom of your Lego dimensions base, there is a print in the middle. On that print it states the model number and the listed consoles it works for. For instance, mine says model/modelo No. ###### for ps3/ps4/WiiU

Answer (score -2):

the WII/PS3/PS4-Version also works with Linux as USB-HID but needs there custom (python) scripts as RFID-Reader and three multicolor LED-Output-Device

Comment: How would it work on Linux? LEGO Dimensions isn't on PC.

Comment: Sure it does. It runs on emulators, as long as you have the portal and discs.